# jQuery children elements are not cooperate

Tags: html, jquery, toggle

How it should work:

- Open (toggle .show class) on div.user, and displays the .userSub div.
- If I click on another div.user, close (remove .show class) and opens the clicked div.userSub
- If I click on the already .show-ed div.user (NOT .userSub), it'd close the target div.user.

Almost works **but the problem**:

- when .userSub div is .show-ed, I can only click to close on the .userSub div, not the .user div. However that would be goal. :)

I've tried to eliminate the problem. Probably the .user selection is wrong and I should use stopPropagation() somewhere, or I should be more specific with the child elements, but I can't figure it out.

```js
let $active
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".user").click(function(e) {
    if ($active != null) {
      $active.toggleClass("show")
    }
    $(e.target).children().toggleClass("show")
    $active = $(e.target).children()
  })
})
```

```css
.user {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.userSub {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user">
  name 1
  <div class="userSub">details 1<button>more 1</button></div>
</div>
<div class="user">
  name 2
  <div class="userSub">details 2<button>more 2</button></div>
</div>
<div class="user">
  name 3
  <div class="userSub">details 3<button>more 3</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your goal check that the clicked element was the `.user` element directly, not a child of it. To do that you can use the `target` property of the event.

Also note that you can simplify the logic by only applying the `.show` class to the parent `.user` and having the CSS rules apply the `display: block` rule to the child elements based on the class on a parent. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let $users = $(".user").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;
  
    $users.not(this).removeClass('show');
    $(this).toggleClass("show")
  })
})
```

```css
.user {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.userSub {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.user.show .userSub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user">
  name 1
  <div class="userSub">details 1<button>more 1</button></div>
</div>
<div class="user">
  name 2
  <div class="userSub">details 2<button>more 2</button></div>
</div>
<div class="user">
  name 3
  <div class="userSub">details 3<button>more 3</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You where just a second faster than me :)

Comment: Haha :) If you don't mind I copied your use of the Element objects for the comparison as it spared the instantiation of a needless jQuery object. I've upvoted another of your answers to say thank you :)

Comment: I don't mind you using any of mine ;) Honored tbh.

Comment: Oh my... I knew there must be an easier solution. :)  And a pretty nice one. ;) Now I could sleep tonight. :) Thank you.